# Travel to canada via Zurich or Munich

Tags: international-travel

I am Bangladeshi passport holder. Travelling to Canada from Abu Dhabi via Zurich or Munich or Frankfruit do I need transit visa in those countries?
Since I have Canada visa and will fly from Abu Dhabi to Toronto via Zurich or Munic without Sengen visa, is there any problem as I am Bangladeshi Passport holder?

Comment: Zurich is in Switzerland, the other two are in Germany, so they are in the Schengen area.